# What does it mean when declaring an object with static keyword?

Tags: c++

I was writing a C++ program and the part of its code is like below

```
#include <cstdio>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        puts("Create");
    }
    ~A()
    {
        puts("Destroy");
    }
};
void Test()
{
    puts("In");
    static A a; //declare an object with static keyword.
}
int main()
{
    Test();
    puts("Out");
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that the *static* keyword would make it like a global variable, and the output of this program should be

```
Create
In
Out
Destroy
```

But the fact was that when I compiled it using GCC, I got some linker errors,

```
/tmp/cc1JwaFb.o: In function `Test()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'
test.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'
test.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_abort'
/tmp/cc1JwaFb.o:(.eh_frame+0x6b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but I can compile it using G++, which outputed

```
In
Create
Out
Destroy
```

So, why did these happen? What does it mean when declaring an object with *static* keyword?

Comment: I compile with a C++ program with a C compiler, why it's didn't work? "GCC" is a multi-compiler, "gcc" is used for C programs. "g++" for C++ program.

Comment: the local static variable has static storage duration and it's not initialized until it's reached by control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is the first time the execution gets to `static A a;` line `A` is created. This happens after `puts("In");` so the output is in the right order.

So far everything is the same as with non-static variable. In your example you still can see that the variable is static because `Out` is printed before `Destroy` (lifetime of a static variable = program lifetime). But one other property of static variable is not displayed in your example. Try the following main:

```
int main()
{
    Test();
    Test();
    puts("Out");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
In
Create
In
Out
Destroy
```

You can see here that "Create" was printed just once. This is what a static variable does - it gets initialized just once, when the execution gets to the declaration first time.

Hope this helps